# Why does Chrome for iOS handle cookies differently?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, cookies

Normally, Google Chrome does not allow secure cookies to be overridden by cookies over unsecured connections.

If you use Chrome on Windows/Mac/Android and try to override a secure cookie over an unsecured connection, the secure cookie stays in place.

But Chrome on iOS overrides the cookie in such situation, which is a security risk.

Why does Chrome for iOS behave differently?

If you want to test this for yourself, then visit three URLs below. The first will write a secure cookie, the second will try to override the same cookie over an unsecured connection, the third will display the result:

- https://v8.prnx.net/hello/set-secure1.asp
- http://v8.prnx.net/hello/set-nonsecure1b.asp
- https://v8.prnx.net/hello/secure1.asp

I have tested this on:

- Chrome 72 on Windows (secure)
- Chrome 72 on Mac (secure)
- Chrome 71 on Android (secure)
- Chrome 72 on iOS (insecure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome on iOS is just a thin wrapper around Apple's [WkWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview). As a consequence, it behaves pretty much the same way as Apple's Safari because Google cannot use their own Blink and Chrome Networking platform implementations due to Apple AppStore rules.

Comment: That explains it; Safari has the same questionable behavior. Thanks.